# If $ab = e$, then $ba = e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$x\cdot (a\cdot b) = x\cdot e$

$(x\cdot a)\cdot b = x$

$e\cdot b = x$

$b = x$

Are my steps correct?
What I wanted to prove is that if $ab = e$, then $ba = e$

$x$ is inverse of $a$ and $e$ is identity element .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the structure from where you took the elements. If it's a group, then it's fine. For an algebraic structure where right identity $\neq$ left identity, or right inverse $\neq$ left inverse, your proposition won't be true.

Comment: The tags include group-theory. I think it's safe to assume the OP means this is a group.

Comment: Yeah, then what he did is perfect. :)

Comment: Well, we want to prove that right-inverse=left-inverse right? So which property of a group guaranties that?

Comment: @red_trumpet we define the algebraic structure 'group' by this way... that it should have an identity. From this part, you can get right inverse = left inverse.

Comment: I think I remember that it was sufficient to require left-inverses for all elements. Those than also are right-inverses. Not sure though, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Ok, I got it: Suppose $ab=e$. Then $ba = b(ab)a = (ba)(ba)$. Multiplying with the right-inverse of $ba$ we get $ba = e$.

Comment: @red_trumpet No, actually any side-inverse is enough, because of the property right identity = left identity. If you start from left inverse, it's fine, if you start from right inverse, then it'll also fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81658/discussion-between-red-trumpet-and-anik-bhowmick).

Comment: Yes, that's just fine !! @red_trumpet

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to introduce $x$ for $a^{-1}$. Since $ab=e$ we have
\begin{align*}
e & = a^{-1}ea\\
 & = a^{-1}(ab)a\\
 & = ba
\end{align*}
by multiplying 
by $a^{-1}$ from the left and then by $a$ from the right. So conjugating $ab=e$ gives $ba=e$.

Comment: Why do you even introduce $a^{-1}$? Do we not know that $b = a^{-1}$?

Comment: @red_trumpet No - the definition of a group explicitly requires that both $ab$ and $ba$ equal $e$ for $b$ to be the inverse of $a$. It could be that there's some $b$ such that $ab=e$ but not $ba=e$, so it wouldn't be the inverse.

Comment: I'm not that sure. I think I remember that if every element has a left inverse, those inverses also are right-inverse. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Ok, I got it: Suppose ab=e. Then ba=b(ab)a=(ba)(ba). Multiplying with the right-inverse of ba we get ba=e.

Comment: @red_trumpet. Indeed, here we do know that $b=a^{-1}$, but in general we $a,b\in G$ and then inverses $a^{-1},b^{-1}$ are standard notation we can use. So why renaming again to a letter $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure what you did was correct. As always with maths, it depends a lot on the context.

If your context is that $a, b, x$ are elements of a group $G$, than it still depends how you did define group. To me it appears like you want to prove that if every element $a \in G$ has a right-inverse $b\in G$, i.e. $ab = e$, then $b$ is also a left-inverse.

If this is what you want to do, then I don't see why your second step is true. You seem to use $x\cdot a = e$, but why is this true?

On the other hand, if you suppose the existance of a right-inverse $b$ and a left-inverse $x$ than it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

One proof if you are referring elements in a group, $a,b,e\in G$ and $ab = e$. Then
$$ba = bea = baba$$
The group $G$ is closed, thus $ba\in G$. Every element in $G$ has an inverse, thus $(ba)^{-1} \in G$. Then by associative property
$$e = (ba)^{-1} ba = [(ba)^{-1} ba ]ba = ba$$

Answer (score 0):

In a group $G$ one has the general property that for all $a$, $b\in G$ the elements $ab$ and $ba$ are conjugated. Indeed one has
$$
ba=b(ab)b^{-1}.
$$
What is asked follows immediately from the observation that the only element conjugated to the identity $e$ is $e$ itself.